# mongoimport Error, Failed: invalid JSON input

Tags: mongodb

I have many mongodb instance files like below;

```
[
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("35d455de983c0e6a53ea0848"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-05T23:25:04.347+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("1ecbe0f75df8ccd52a7b1662"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-17T12:40:53.521+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
]
```

I couldn't import these files because of invalid format.

```
mongoimport --db DATABASENAME --collection COLLECTIONNAME --file filename.json --jsonArray
```

And it says;

> Failed: invalid JSON input. Position: 16. Character: O

Is there any other way to import those files?

If not, how can I convert them to be imported?

Comment: That is not valid json you are trying to import. What happens when you remove the ending `--jsonArray`?

Comment: `mongoimport` is rum from operating system command prompt. The JSON data and the import command used above are fine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you can use `--legacy` option of `mongoimport` in order to import the file with the format you want with ObjectId("an oid"), NumberInt(an int) or new Date("an iso date" or any mongo extension available in extended json v1 :  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/)

Comment: This would be the best answer.

Comment: Amazing! Best answer for me!

Comment: `mongoimport -d DbName -c CollectionName --legacy fileName.json` Adding the actual command that I used to resolve this error.  (Giving it here so others won't need to search for syntax)

Comment: Awesome. Helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1** (semi-auto):

We can import database only in json/csv format so remove all invalid characters such as `ObjectId`, `ISODate`, `NumberInt`, `()`...

**Solution2** (auto):

Finally, I found an alternative solution.

We can't import such data even in Mongo Compass.

But fortunately, we can import/export database in various formats in [Studio 3T for MongoDB](https://studio3t.com).

I think Studio 3T is better than Mongo Compass, but it is not free.
After 30 days, we can't use Studio 3T trial version.

I will be very thankful if you let me know a way to reset Studio 3T.

Comment: Yes Studio 3T is better. But it is also not free. Only a 30 days free trial.

Comment: @Cedric Indeed!

Answer (score 1):

> invalid JSON input. Position: 96. Character: N

For me it was "N" for NaN that I replaced with 0 and it wroked.

[image]

It also worked with adding the --legacy option, but I preferred to fix the file as the legacy option did not work within my docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, the error was about a property called '$init' that was added by mongoose automatically.
I removed all those by Sublime and imported again by 3T.